# Kart plugin for QGIS returns Python errors

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, kart

The problem concerns: https://kartproject.org. When I am trying to do multiple things in Kart QGIS plugin (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/kart) like:

- Add to QGIS

  [image]
- Display properties

  [image]

I got Python error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Details:

```
File "C:\Users/lstem/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\kart\gui\dockwidget.py", line 156, in wrapper
  f(*args)
  File "C:\Users/lstem/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\kart\gui\dockwidget.py", line 370, in showProperties
  dialog = RepoPropertiesDialog(self.repo)
  File "C:\Users/lstem/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\kart\gui\repopropertiesdialog.py", line 39, in __init__
  self.populate()
  File "C:\Users/lstem/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\kart\kartapi.py", line 56, in inner
  return f(*args)
  File "C:\Users/lstem/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\kart\gui\repopropertiesdialog.py", line 45, in populate
  self.labelWorkingCopyLocation.setText(self.repo.workingCopyLocation())
  File "C:\Users/lstem/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\kart\kartapi.py", line 719, in workingCopyLocation
  return self._config()["kart.workingcopy.location"]
  File "C:\Users/lstem/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\kart\kartapi.py", line 382, in _config
  lines = ret.splitlines()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

And when I manually added Kart.gpkg, modified geometry and wanted to see changes I've got:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/lstem/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\kart\gui\diffviewer.py", line 399, in fillCanvas
    crs = self.oldLayer.crs()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

I've installed Kart 0.14 on my Windows 11 Machine and I am using QGIS 3.28.4-Firenze and Kart plugin 1.0.12.

What can I do?

Comment: Unable to test this in win11, but this looks to be an error caused by another underlying error getting config information from the underlying kart process. What happens if you run `kart.exe config -l` in a command line?